# Symfony basic HTTP authentication not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, authentication

In a project using Symfony 2.8.14 I am using a very basic setup to enable basic HTTP Authentication in Symfony as described in http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security.html

*security.yml*

```
security:

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    myuser: { password: mypassword, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }

    firewalls:
        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/myroute, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

When accessing `/myroute` on my local server I am prompted with the HTTP basic auth prompt. However, after entering the correct credentials, it just keeps showing me the prompt.

On a remote server there will be infinite "redirects" to the same route with a `401` status code after entering the correct credentials.

Both servers are running Apache 2.4 with PHP via FastCGI. There are other threads suggesting to add

```
# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

to the `/web/.htaccess` due to a specific problem with Apache running PHP via FastCGI. However, this is already incorporated into the `symfony/standard-edition` (and is also present in my `.htaccess`).

I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the notes on http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php suggested adding this:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

That helped. It appears the default `.htaccess` config of the `symfony/standard-edition` is not enough (at least in some Environments).

Answer (score 2):

Try specify this under firewalls:

```
firewalls:
    default:
        pattern:      ^/myroute
        anonymous: false
        provider: in_memory
```

Hope this help

Answer (score -1):

You have to do this (go to new line)

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                myuser:
                    { password: mypassword, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
```

or you can also explose the array like this

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                myuser:
                    password: mypassword
                    roles: 'ROLE_USER'
```

Otherwise myuser is considered as a string with value "{ password: mypassword, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }"

Comment: No, you don't have to do a new line when you use the curly brackets. The problem was something else entirely (see answer).

Comment: I just tried it myself yesterday and it didn't work until i inserted a new line !

Comment: Must have been some other problem. New lines are not required in YAML when using any kind of brackets: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html

Comment: Well i had use your security.yml and it just worked with a new line.

Comment: Did your server environment use Apache with PHP running via FastCGI?